# Changes to app.rb don't seem to go into effect

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to test a GET request in sendRequest.js:

```
$.get( '/test/test2', {name: 'Larry', time: '2pm'} );
```

This sends the request fine and everything works on the JavaScript end, but obviously returns a 404 (route not found) so I added in app.rb:

```
get '/test/test2' do
    logger.info "this is a test log"
end
```

I sent the request again, and I got the same 404.

This scenario originates from none of my changes in app.rb going into effect. I've deleted entire routes, commented stuff out, etc., nothing I do in app.rb seems to have any effect on the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried stopping and restarting the server?

By default Sinatra won't know its code has changed, and Ruby will have loaded all the script into memory and won't look at the file.

Stopping the server, by using <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then restarting the server will refresh Ruby's idea of what should be done.